# Labelling in arcGIS Pro

Tags: label, arcgis

Hi stackoverflow world,

Wondering if anyone has experience in creating multi-color circular labels using ArcGIS pro similar to the attached image. Would love any suggestions !!!

I've explored the label properties and symbology properties with no luck so far.